# Increase efficency in list rearranging

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'class': ['title is-5', 'company', 'location']}, 
{'class': ['subtitle is-3', 'title is-1']}]
```

The goal is to turn that into 2 separate lists like this:

```
[[{'class': 'title is-5'}, {'class': 'company'}, {'class': 'location'}], 
[{'class': 'subtitle is-3'}, {'class': 'title is-1'}]]
```

I wrote a function that accomplishes that:

```
def AggregateAttributes(config_attr: list):
    final_attr_list = []
    for list_attr in config_attr:
        attr_value_list = []
        for key, val in list_attr.items():
            for attr_val in val:
                attr_value_list.append({key: attr_val})
        final_attr_list.append(attr_value_list)
    return final_attr_list
```

Is there a way to do this without having to use 3 for loops?? I feel like this solution is super inefficient.

Comment: Why do you have the second loop? If you have 3 nested structures and if the length is not fixed to 1 you need 3 loops.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a short hand syntax that allows you to compile some pretty complicated iterables (lists, dicts, etc.) in a single line.

This will do the trick for you:

```
dict_list = [{'class': ['title is-5', 'company', 'location']}, {'class': ['subtitle is-3', 'title is-1']}]

my_list = [[{'class':v} for v in dict_list[i]['class']] for i in range(len(dict_list))]

print(my_list)
```

As a simpler example, I cam make a list of 1200 integers from 0 to 1199 like this:

```
my_list = [i for i in range(0, 1200)]
```

within this line I have the flexibility to make edits before the final list is created.  Let's say I wanted integer values to be the chr() representations.

```
my_list = [chr(i) for i in range(100)]
```

or strings...

```
my_list = [str(i) for i in range(100)]
```

The last one is identical to this:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(100):
    my_list.append(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your code is already efficient. Just make it into list comprehension and it will be faster.

```
[[{key: attr_val} for attr_val in val] for list_attr in a for key,val in list_attr.items() ]

%timeit [[{key: attr_val} for attr_val in val] for list_attr in a for key,val in list_attr.items() ]

1.87 µs ± 85.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Of course, without defining it with a function will have slightly faster performance, yet not reusable

Comment: actually, in python, code executed in a function is slightly faster than code executed outside (because local variable accesses are faster than global, though this is probably negligible here since there is only one of those)

Comment: That's true, I will still prefer to enclose it into a function too :)